# Error received saying Provider is not set, when trying to call a function, after deploying a contract

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation, web3-providers

Should we set provider for contract instances separately or am I missing something. Is there any problem setting it to current provider instance?
I am using the "1.0.0-beta.26" web3.

The error is received after I deploy the contract (successfully) and try to call the offerBet function.

Here is the code

```
var Web3 = require("Web3");
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
web3.eth.getAccounts().then((accounts)=>{
    web3.eth.defaultAccount = accounts[0];
    console.log("Default Account", web3.eth.defaultAccount);
    //To be used from the console
    module.exports.web3   = web3;
    module.exports.party1 = accounts[1];
    module.exports.party2 = accounts[2];
})

var solc = require("solc");
var src = `pragma solidity ^0.4.19;
contract coinFlipper{
    mapping(uint=>address) parties;
    mapping(address=>uint) bets;

    enum GameState { betOpen, betWaiting, betClosed}
    GameState public coinFlip;

    function coinFlipper() public{
        coinFlip = GameState.betOpen;
    }

    function offerBet(uint _amount) public payable {
        require(coinFlip == GameState.betOpen);
        coinFlip = GameState.betWaiting;
        parties[0] = msg.sender;
        bets[msg.sender] = _amount;
    }

    function meetBet(uint _amount) public payable {
        require(coinFlip == GameState.betWaiting);
        require(_amount >= bets[parties[0]]);
        coinFlip = GameState.betClosed;
        parties[1] = msg.sender;
        bets[msg.sender] = _amount;
    }

}`;

//Helper functions to play around in the console
module.exports = {
    //Prepares the contract deploy transaction
    deployCoinFlipper : function(){

        var compiled            = solc.compile(src);
        //console.log("compiled", compiled);
        var compiledContract    = compiled.contracts[":coinFlipper"];
        var abi                 = JSON.parse(compiledContract.interface);
        var coinFlipper         = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, '', {
            from: web3.eth.defaultAccount
        });

        coinFlipper.options = {
            jsonInterface: abi,
            from : web3.eth.defaultAccount,
            data : '0x' + compiledContract.bytecode,
            gas : 4700000,
            gasPrice : 10
        };

        var deployed = coinFlipper.deploy(coinFlipper.options);
        return deployed;
    },

    //Calls the contract offerBet function
    offerBet : function(contract, party, amount){
        contract.methods.offerBet(amount).send({from:party})
        .then(receipt => console.log(receipt));
    },

    //Calls the contract meetBet function
    meetBet : function(contract, party, amount){
        contract.methods.meetBet(amount).send({from:party})
        .then(receipt => console.log(receipt));
    },
}
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: ok. added the code.